# How to find second Monday of month

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I need to find the second Monday of a month e.g. for Sep 2021, the second Monday is 13th
How do I do this in Snowflake SQL.

Comment: Just find month number of current date. Then increase month  by 1. Then find starting week number then increase week by 1. Get Monday of this week.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer on a separate [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52218479/how-to-get-second-wednesday-of-the-month)

```
select 
extract(dow from current_date) = 1 
and extract(day from current_date) between 8 and 14;
```